# Why doesn't the Ubuntu installer notice my existing Ubuntu installation?

Tags: installation, xubuntu

Yesterday I downloaded Ubuntu 12.10 and I installed it along side my Windows XP installation. Then since it was running slow, I decided to remove XP. I decided to do a fresh install of Ubuntu via USB.

So when I was installing it, it detected that my PC has a Windows XP installation, but it didn't show that I already have Ubuntu or anything like that. Should I continue just by formatting Windows XP or should I do something else?

Comment: Did you use Wubi to install ubuntu from within XP?

Comment: Are you trying to install Xubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

I have had success in the past by reformatting using gparted and wiping the entire drive and then doing a fresh install of Ubuntu after that. You can make a live USB [here](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/liveusb.php). After you have wiped the entire drive just do a fresh install of Ubuntu.

---

You can also just select use the entire drive on Ubuntu when installing.